# Can't use WinUI 3 File Picker

Tags: c#, winui-3, filepicker

I'm trying to show a file picker in my Windows App SDK (WinUI 3) application. I'm making it in C#.

Here's my function to show the file picker:

```cs
private async Task<StorageFile> PickFileAsync()
{
    var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    var hwnd = this.XamlRoot.Content.XamlRoot.WindowId;

    WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(filePicker, hwnd);

    StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
        return file;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the function:

```cs
StorageFile pickedFile = await PickFileAsync();
```

Just in case it matters, I'm calling the function from another function which is defined as `private`, `async`, and `void`.

By the way, I've put the `PickFileAsync()` method in the `.cs` code for one of my app's pages, since the page contains the menu which triggers the action.

There are very few articles showing this so I couldn't really do much research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example if you want to open the file picker on a `Page`.

First, make your `MainWindow` accessible from your page. One way to do this is by make it `public static`:

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace FilePickerExample;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Window? Window { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Window = new MainWindow();
        Window.Activate();
    }
}
```

and in your page:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using WinRT.Interop;

namespace FilePickerExample;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new()
        {
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            FileTypeFilter = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif" },
        };

        nint windowHandle = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(App.Window);
        InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(fileOpenPicker, windowHandle);

        StorageFile file = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            // Do something with the file.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, because the MainWindow is referenced.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `GetWindowHandle` method to get the window handle. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/ui-input/retrieve-hwnd#winui-3-with-c

```cs
var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
...

var hwnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);

WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(filePicker, hwnd);

StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

Comment: Does this work for a `Page` too? Just updated my question.

Comment: When I run the code you provided, Visual Studio gives me the error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` and points to the line that defines the `hwnd` variable.

Comment: You need to pass a `Window` to `GetWindowHandle()`. You can make your `MainWindow` accessible from **App.xaml.cs** like this: `public static Window? Window { get; private set; }`.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding How would I then put that as the argument to the call to `GetWindowHandle()`? I tried `var hwnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(Window);`, but that didn't work.

Comment: In App.xaml.cs, set the `Window` property when you create the `MainWindow`. Since `Window` is a static property, you can get the `MainWindow` in your page like this: `nint windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(App.Window);`

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding Now I get this error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` stemming from the `GetWindowHandle()` call.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I tried to show the contents of `App.Window` in a Toast notification, now it's giving me this useful error: `TexType_V2.App.Window.get returned null.`. So `App.Window` is null?

Comment: Did you set the `Window` in App.xaml.cs? `Window = new  MainWindow()`

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding Where would I put that code?

Comment: Posted an answer. Hope it helps. Let me know if you have further questions.