CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Converters don't work as per documentation
Continuing my saga in WPF to WinUI migration (part 1 can be viewed here). Because I'm already using the Community Toolkit for MVVM I'm using some of the other offerings there as well.
I tried, rather than my old approach of using a custom converter, using the ones found in CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Converters. The documentation says that it's as simple as 1-2-3

Add the namespace

xmlns:converters="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Converters"


Add the resource

<Page.Resources>
   <converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>


Call it from your XAML

<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind viewModel.SelectedWorkbook.CountOfWorksheets, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}Count of worksheets: {0}'}"/>

But this fails at build time with an error like follows:

CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Company.Dept.App.Views.MainWindow' to 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement'

This is a normal C# error like what you'd get when trying to do something assigning a variable of type string to a variable of type integer, but I don't understand why it manifests itself here when using this converter in exactly the way that the documentation prescribes.
Is there a simple fix for this?
** EDIT **
I noticed the documentation has the namespace hanging off a Page element so I changed it to this, but it didn't make a whit of a difference.

IIRC, I've seen that error when I tried to use a converter in a Window.

Unlike WPF, in WinUI you can't use value converters in the Window class XAML.
So, the following code:
<Window
    x:Class="WinUIDemoApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIDemoApp"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:SomeValueConverter x:Key="SomeValueConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button Content="{x:Bind SomeText, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SomeValueConverter}}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>

will give you this error:
CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WinUIDemoApp.MainWindow' to 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement'

There is an open issue in the WinUI GitHub repo about this.
So, I recommend using the Window as a wrapper and placing a Page with your contents in it.
<Window...>
    <local:MainPage />
</Window>


More of the 2 steps forward-1 step back here when do this. I'm using a FilePicker from the Community Toolkit as well, and showing that from a RelayCommand in the VM. This requires a hWnd to work so I'm passing that as follows:
<Button Content="Open a file" Command="{x:Bind viewModel.PickFileCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Bind AppWindow}"/>


If I do what you suggest the Page gives out saying that it knows nothing about the AppWindow. I changed to read:
<Button Content="Open a file" Command="{x:Bind viewModel.PickFileCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Bind local:MainWindow.Current.AppWindow.OwnerWindowId}"/>

But this causes the method where the file picker is used to fail as the OwnerWindowId value is null. I suppose now I have to go down the route of Service Locators etc.?

This answer might help you with the FileOpenPicker.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76448851/2411960
